# Node.js watching a file

Tags: node.js

I want to print a message whenever the file that I am watching has changed. I am able to do that using `console.log` but I couldn't figure out how to do that using `response.write` or similar functions.

```
var counter = 0;
const
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    filename = process.argv[2];

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/plain' });
    counter = counter + 1;
    response.end('Hello client ' + Math.round(counter / 2));
});

server.on('listening', function() {
    var watcher = fs.watch(filename, function(){
    console.log('The file ' + filename + ' has just changed.');
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Also, the reason why I have done that `Math.round(counter / 2)` is because counter is increasing by 2 each time a client is connected. I was wondering why this is happening and if there is a better technique to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

For you to be able to do it using `response.write` it would need to be part of your server request handler function.

File events can occur independently of someone sending a request, so it's handling is independent to that of handling a request. Because of this, there is no associated request for you to write to.

If you want to keep track of all the file change events and then show it to the user whenever they do send a request, consider storing the information about changes in an object outside your handler functions and when the a request takes place, read that object to see if there have been changes and write a response based on it to the user.

Comment: So if a user has connected and after that the file has changed is it not possible to generate a new response without the user sending a new request?

Comment: Since you're calling `response.end()` you're sending all of the data at once to the user. You could consider using `response.write()` (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) to write chunks of data, which would keep that connection and keep sending data to the same response, but that seems like a weird thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inform an end user that the file has change, for example in a web browser, then you have a number of options, including polling the server or using websockets.

I would recommend you take a look at [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

It is easy to implement and there are npm module out there to make it even easier in node.js. e.g. [npm sse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sse)

Answer (score 0):

You can try node module chokidar 
    https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar 
it is a gread module for file watching